# Xampp: Class 'RarArchive' not found

Tags: php, xampp, php-5.6

I'm working with a php script which extract rar files. I need to make it works on xammp with **php 5.6**.

In order to install the rar class I have :

- put **php_rar.dll** (compatible with **php 5.6**) inside the *C:\xampp\php\ext* folder
- added *extension=php_rar.dll* inside **php.ini**
- restart apache service

Here is my code

```
<?php
    $archive = RarArchive::open('./lobo.rar');
    $entries = $archive->getEntries();
    foreach ($entries as $entry) {
        $entry->extract('./');
    }
    $archive->close();
?>
```

I still have this error

[image]

**EDIT**

The extension is not present in phpinfo()

In the error.log : PHP Fatal error: Class 'RarArchive' not found in C:\xampp\htdocs\myproject\index.php on line 2

Comment: Did you try to place `\\` before the class name?

Comment: Sorry I don't understand. Can you be more explicit please?

Comment: `\RarArchive` instead `RarArchive`

Comment: I still have my error

Comment: Wouldn't you at least check phpinfo(), `php -m` or the error.log to see if the extension was really present?

Comment: The extension is not present in phpinfo()

Comment: In the error.log : PHP Fatal error:  Class 'RarArchive' not found in C:\\xampp\\htdocs\\myproject\\index.php on line 2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The PHP_RAR has dependency to PEAR. See [this](https://pecl.php.net/package/rar) for more information.
And you may install PEAR following [this link](http://pear.php.net/manual/en/installation.getting.php).

If you install pear in windows, remember to user command-line tool with administrator privilege.

After installing PEAR, I think your problem will be solved.